# How to convert int values into bytes in java

Tags: java

Hi friends. I am new in java and I was trying to print the value of

```
int z=123456;
System.out.println((short)z);
```

and the o/p is coming :  -7616

Can anybody explain to me why it is happening?
Thanks in advance;

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: It overflows at 32767, because that is the maximum value for `short` in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum value for a signed 16-bit integer is `32767`, so if you try to convert a larger number, it will overflow and turn negative, unless you wrap around a second time.

Let is consider the number `123456`. If we compute `123456 % (2^16)`, we will get  `57920`.

The byte representation is `0b1110001001000000`, which is equal to `-7616` in 2's complement.

To make it more obvious, we can compute the 2's complement as follows.

```
(0b0110001001000000 - 2^15) = -7616
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this value is comming i am not getting..?

Answer (score 0):

Range of `int` :  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Range of `short` : -32,768 to 32,767

Now when you take a short variable with value 32767 and add 1, the output will be -32768. That is, when the result of some calculation exceeds the range then it continues from the other extreme end. This can be explained using binary representation.

```
eg. consider a number of 3 bits. Range will be -4 to 3. i.e. (100, 101, 110, 111, 000, 001, 010, 011) respectively.
So if you add 1 to 3 you would be doing: 001 + 011 = 100 which is nothing but -4.

Note: Also remember that while calculating, any extra bit(extra carry) is to be ignored.
```

So when you converted 123456 to `short`, the output will be the one produced assuming that after 32767 the counting will start from -32768

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that you are narrowing primitives, more about that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.3

in this specific case
123456 in base2 32 bit (integer (primitive!) in Java is 32bit) 2nd complement (that is how Java stores primitives): 00000000000000011110001001000000

if you narrow (in this case to short which is 16 bit) the 2nd complement binary representation is gonna be: 1110001001000000 which is -7616